# Run a regression with omitted category

Tags: r

I have a dataset like these

| BirthYear | walking |
| --- | --- |
| 50-70 | 500 |
| 70-90 | 700 |
| 90-10 | 200 |
| 70-90 | 450 |
| 70-90 | 850 |
| 70-90 | 890 |
| 30-50 | 660 |
| 70-90 | 760 |
| 70-90 | 450 |
| 30-50 | 230 |
| 30-50 | 120 |
| 50-70 | 120 |
| 70-90 | 340 |
| 90-10 | 920 |

I want to run a regression of walking on BirthYear and that the BirthYear 90-10 is the omitted category, to find out how much 70-90 people walk less than 90-10 people on average.

I gave this code but don't  know how to fix with omitted category for 90-10.

```
feols(fml = walking ~ BirthYear, data = df)
```

Comment: I don't understand, why are you omitting the 90-10 age category?

Comment: To make some analysis

Comment: But why would you do that? You should include it in the model if you want to make any sort of comparison with it.

Comment: to find out how much 70-90 walk less than 90-10 on average

Comment: Then you need to include this age category in the model, and either put the 70-90 category as the reference or build a contrast between these two categories.

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to do that to put the 70-90 as reference

Comment: Maybe I did not explain it, but that what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put the 70-90 category in the reference/intercept simply use the relevel function

```
> df$BirthYear=factor(df$BirthYear)
> df$BirthYear=relevel(df$BirthYear,"70-90")
> summary(lm(walking~BirthYear,data=df))

Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)      634.29     105.62   6.006 0.000131 ***
BirthYear30-50  -297.62     192.83  -1.543 0.153754    
BirthYear50-70  -324.29     224.05  -1.447 0.178396    
BirthYear90-10   -74.29     224.05  -0.332 0.747062
```

Comment: but how is the code, if I want a omitting category?

Comment: @Jau This is the code, the `relevel` call specifically.